# translate stata codes in r, but the outcomes are different

Tags: r, stata

I'm currently working on a replication of a paper. The author uses Stata, which I know very little about it, therefore I must translate it to R.  I have one question about the following codes:

```
use "${directory_data}/income_dataset.dta", clear
reghdfe log_income post61_sc post65_sc male std_score mean_score_class privatista non_bocciato  if tipo_scuola2==1 & laureato==1, vce(cluster liceo_anno) absorb(liceo anno_maturita prov_nasc abilita_anno liceo_anno major_2)
sum log_income if e(sample)
local mean=r(mean)
local mean=round(`mean',.01)
local sd=r(sd)
local sd=round(`sd',.01)
```

```
reghdfe log_income post61_sc post65_sc male std_score mean_score_class privatista non_bocciato if tipo_scuola2==1 & laureato==1, vce(cluster liceo_anno) absorb(prov_nasc prov_res_anno liceo_anno abilita_anno major_2)
sum log_income if e(sample)
local mean=r(mean)
local mean=round(`mean',.01)
local sd=r(sd)
local sd=round(`sd',.01)
```

I assume that I will get the same mean and sd from these two regressions. Because I subset the data by the same conditions  `tipo_scuola2==1 & laureato==1`. However, the outcomes are not the same.

And my replication for the first regression is :

```
income5.1 <-subset(income,tipo_scuola2==1 & laureato==1 & !is.na(income$log_income))
income5.1m <- round(mean(income5.1$log_income),digits = 2)
income5.1s <- round(sd(income5.1$log_income),digits = 2)
tb5.1 <- felm(log_income ~ post61_sc+ post65_sc+ male+ std_score+ mean_score_class+ privatista +non_bocciato|liceo +anno_maturita +prov_nasc +abilita_anno +liceo_anno+ major_2|0|liceo_anno,data = income5.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is impossible to verify without a seeing the data (use `dataex` from SSC -- `ssc install dataex` to create a sample dataset):

The difference likely arises because [`reghdfe`](http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/) drops singletons (groups with only one observation), while `felm` does not. So the sample you are using in R and Stata are not the same, creating differences you observe. Note also that, even when using the same data `reghdfe` and `felm` have different methods for computing clustered standard errors. There are several deeper discussions of this issue on [Github](https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/issues/1).

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that `reghdfe` drops singletons. After manually removing all singletons, I got the same sample and the same results.